# Can a Tableau filter be used in multiple ways simultaneously?

Tags: filtering, tableau-desktop, calculated-field

I have built a Dashboard that has two filter worksheets within it.

The first worksheet contains all the transactions for all the clients while the other Worksheet only contains Payouts.

What I am looking to do is add a (Transaction number) filter to the dashboard, once the user selects a specific  number, I want the table that contains all the transactions to be filtered for the user_id of the respective Transaction Number selected, while the other table containing only payouts would filter normally based on the Transaction numbers.

Further explanation: Lets say we have a total of 100 transactions (shown in the first worksheet), 30 of them are payouts (shown in the second worksheet), now lets assume that the user selects one transaction number (id = abc) through the filter control, and that transaction belongs to client 123, what I would like to do is show all the transactions belonging to client 123 in the first worksheet, while only showing transaction abc in the second worksheet

Is this something doable in Tableau? I am assuming I will need to create calculated fields for this but I am finding hard to create the logic.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

I have tried implementing this through creating calculated fields, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: IMO you should use a parameter to select the transaction number, then create a calculated field that selects all the transactions belonging to the user corresponding. You then use this calculated field as a filter. Make it as the default value is "all" and if it is set to this then show everyone

Comment: I have tried this, the issue with this approach is, I could not create a parameter that refreshes as the workbook open (to get the latest transactions) and add another field 'All' to the List. Adding an extra field is only possible when 'Fixed' is selected which doesn't allow for automatic refreshes.
Please correct me if I am wrong in my understanding.